Receiving wrong amount of tokens during swap

I have been trying to construct a transaction to swap sol to a given pump.fun token. In this example I have tried to swap 0.001 sol to this Hamster coin but instead I am only receiving 1 token in exchange. This happens for every pump.fun token I try and can't seem to figure out why.
